# what $finish will be sythesis to in verilog?

Tags: verilog, register-transfer-level

For the digital computer, there always has a halt mode which basically mean to turn off the system.

In the verilog, a $finish is used in verilog code.

I am just wondering how the synthesizer will synthesize this.

Answer (score 0):

In Verilog ,commands that start with $ sign are called system functions(/task).
system functions are only called in simulation to control events and synthesis tools will ignore them. (depending on your synthesis tool some of them (e.g $readmem) may get synthesized.)

`$finish` terminates the simulation when called in simulation.

HDLs only provide a description of a designed hardware for simulation or (e.g. FPGA) synthesize porpuses. in the end, all the high-level codes of the RTL design must be translated(*synthesized) to a gate level circuit. So It's quite meaningless to think of it in a programming fashion and calling a function to mimic a hardware behavior.

Comment: does it mean in the real system, the $finish has to be implemented by a add-on specific hardware (either a software shutdown sequence or hardware logic to turn off the CPU)?